# OpenCL and CUDA registers usage optimization

Tags: optimization, cuda, opencl

I'm currently writing an OpenCL kernel (but I suppose that in CUDA in will be the same), and currently I try to optimize for NVidia GPU.

I currently use 63 registers in my kernel, this kernel is very big and so it use all the GPU registers. I'm looking for some way to:

1) See which variables are in registers and which are then in global memory (Because if I have not enough registers it seems the compiler save the variables in global memory).

2) Is there a way to specify which variable is more important (or which should be in registers). Because I use some variables that are present but less used. A way to give priority ?

Is there other optimization strategy when we already use all the registers ?

BTW : I have also try to read the PTX code and search for all the ".reg" keywords but the problem is that the PTX is unreadable, I don't know which register is used for which variable in my code. I have'nt find any way to have the correspondance !

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> See which variables are in registers and which are then in global
>   memory

For this i do not know the way how to check it, however

> Is there a way to specify which variable is more important

One trick that i use when i see that i have spilled registers (due to lack of them or when i need to use dynamic indexing in local vars, which is bad) is to explicitly store ones, that i think are not so critical, into local memory (called "shared" in CUDA)

e.g. before:

```
uint16 somedata;
```

after:

```
__local uint16 somedata[WG_SIZE]; // or __local uint someadata[16];
```

but  beware that if your local memory usage will be greatly increased you are risking to have penalty because number of inflight wavefronts will be less ( i.e. you might have lower occupancy)

Hope this helps.

Comment: __local uint16 somedata means all threads in the group will see the same variable instead of a private copy, so it will cause different behavior.

Comment: yes you are right, i made a typo, actualyy i should have writen __local uint16 somedata[WG_SIZE]; I'll correct it.

Answer (score 3):

(1) It's called register spilling. I don't think there is a way to find out which variables get spilled except examining the SASS assembly. OpenCL first gets compiled to PTX, which is a virtual machine with an infinite number of registers (no spilling). See the NVIDIA presentation [Local Memory and Register Spilling](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/register_spilling.pdf) for more information.

(2) You can try using the `volatile` keyword when declaring the variables that you don't want to keep in registers. `volatile` will force the compiler to push the variable out to memory instead of carrying it in a register between operations.

Comment: `volatile` also prevents a lot of optimizations however so it's not necessarily a win.

Comment: volatile is a bad idea, because _every_ time the variable is used, there will be a read. And from global memory, this will be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code, one way to try to "force" the use of registers can be to use local copies in a limited scope.
Maybe only some of your variables are accessed in a given part of your code. Then you can declare new variables in a scope and use these intensively. There is no guarantee, but I know it helps sometimes.

```
int a, b, d;
double x,y;

...

{
     int ra = a;     // copy into new variables more likely to be kept in registers
     double rx = x;

     ... use rx and ra ...

     a = ra;
     b = rx;       // copy back.
}

...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers,

I have also try to read the PTX code and search for all the ".reg" keywords but the problem is that the PTX is unreadable, I don't know which register is used for which variable in my code. I have'nt find any way to have the correspondance !

Comment: It seems that the best way to optimize registers usage is using {...} to define scope. I'm surprised that the compiler is not able to do this without any help !

Comment: Something else... In CUDA we can use the cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig method to increase the size of the L1 cache. Does someone know if there is a way to call it from an OpenCL software, even if it is not really standard !

Comment: Another related questions:  
  
1) Does my structures are also stored in register or in global memory, L1 etc ?  

2) If my values are put in L1 cache, then it can also suffer from memory banks conflicts ?  
  
Thanks