# The magic number of OpenCl registers

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I wrote two different openCl kernels, used the nvidia profiler to get some information on them and found that both were using 63 registers per work-item.

I tried everything I could think of to lower this number (replace int with ushort, tried to declare variables inside {} to show the compiler when it could get rid of them) but it seems impossible to have this 63 changed!

Then I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726527/opencl-and-cuda-registers-usage-optimization) about a kernel he wrote that uses...again 63 registers.

Of course this could be pure coincidence, but maybe there is a reason behind...a specific function used, a hardware limitation? Does anyone know?

Comment: Why do you think using `ushort` instead of `int` would reduce the number of registers used?

Comment: Because registers are used to store variables frequently used and thus avoid costly access to global/local memory. So if you store float and ushort instead of double and int, you save some space. I tried a simple kernel and effectively saw that using a new double variable used two registers, which makes sense as a register is 32bit and a double is 64.

Comment: You save registers when going from 64bit to 32bit, that much is true. However, since the registers are 32bit anyways, it is very unlikely that going to a ushort` will win you anything. About the caching of variables: I'm not sure if avoiding explicit accesses to local/global memory is legal, since other workitems could modify the memory. For local variables in your kernel: Those should  typically all reside in registers (until you get to hardware limits at least). Storing them in global memory would be very slow and local memory is to limited (not really bigger then register space anyways).

Comment: When I read in the official doc "devices with compute capability 1.0 and 1.1 have 8,192 32-bit registers per multiprocessor", I don't know if it means that I can use 8,192*32 bit for the register, meaning that two ushorts (which are 16-bit each) can fit in one 32-bit register, or if I can't have more than 8,192 variables stored in the register, no matter their size. In that case using ushort would be effectively be useless for my purpose. But I still wonder if "63" corresponds to something or not.

Comment: In theory the compiler could choost two store two variables in one register, however it is unlikely to do so, since it makes the resulting code much more complex (to work with the variable it needs to be extracted from the register, ...), meaning slower. Can't help you with the 63 though.

Comment: never had such issue, but maybe compiler just thinks that it is ok to use 64 registers without any harm (e.g. occupancy etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

63 registers is the max. amount on most of the recent hardware like GTX 480 up to GTX 770. Only with a GTX 780 or Tesla K20 you get 255 registers per thread.

So when your kernel uses 63 registers it is most likely using more than 63 but they will be spilled to off-chip private memory (aka CUDA local memory). For example if your nvidia profiler reports 128bytes of local memory it means you need to get rid of 32 (spilled) registers before you can get below 63 hardware registers.

BTW: "8,192 32-bit registers per multiprocessor" means 8,192 registers for all the workgroups that are resident on the multiprocessor. But usually the number of workgroups is bound by the size of your workgroups and the number of registers your kernel needs. So for example if your kernel uses 63 registers and you have a workgroup size of 16^2 you get: 63*16^2 = 16128 registers per workgroup. Let's assume you have 64K registers per multiprocessor, then you can have 4 workgroups resident on each multiprocessor which would yield an occupancy of 25%.

Answer (score 0):

The max. number of registers/thread is limited by hw and it depends on the 'compute capability' of the device. Take a look at the table
[Compute Capabilities](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities).

(This applies to NVidia, other vendors might have other limits).